# Form Post return no result, but GET works

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried to change method to "GET" and its work, it print out in the URL, with the dateFrom and dateTo, but when I change to post and i do a print_r($_POST); the array is empty

What is wrong with my form

**Thanks!!**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
From <select name="dateFrom">
<option value="03-Sep-2014">03-Sep-2014</option>
<option value="31-Aug-2014">31-Aug-2014</option>
<option value="30-Aug-2014">30-Aug-2014</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
To <select name="dateTo">
<option value="03-Sep-2014">03-Sep-2014</option>
<option value="31-Aug-2014">31-Aug-2014</option>
<option value="30-Aug-2014">30-Aug-2014</option>
</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="View">
</form>
```

And I did this to read my form

```
<?php
include '../inc/session_info.php';

$action = $_GET['action'];
$action_id = $_GET['action_id'];

//if filter by date
print_r($_POST);

$post_dateFrom = $_POST['dateFrom'];
$post_dateTo = $_POST['dateTo'];

echo $postDateFrom;
```

But nothing is echo out or print_r, array was empty

Comment: @Prix, added the php code

Comment: @Prix I found the issue, i should use form method="post" instead of "POST"

Comment: Then kindly click on the `Post Your Answer` button below your question, and answer you own question with that and accept it when possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I change my

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

din't know cap sensitive for the method. it ssolved my issues

Comment: As far as I know HTML is not case sensitive; but XHTML is and it requires lowercase.